# Qual a diferença entre "ama quem te ame" e "ama quem te ama"

Tags: verbos, modo-subjuntivo

Eu sempre fico em dúvida, neste tipo de situação — "eu jogo jogos que eu gosto/goste", por exemplo.

Hipótese:

Se eu só gosto de macarrão, e, no restaurante, só vou comer o que eu gosto, só vou comer macarrão; se eu só gosto de macarrão, e, no restaurante, só vou comer o que eu goste, é possível eu tentar pão de queijo, mas se eu não gostar de pão de queijo — blasfêmia! —, não vou comer mais pão de queijo.

No shopping, só vou comprar o que eu goste, então, se eu não gostar ou se eu não gosto dalgo, não comprarei esse algo; no shopping, só vou comprar o que eu gosto, então, se eu não gosto dalgo, não comprarei esse algo.

Essa hipótese minha está correta?

Comment: Não me sinto qualificado a responder... é que provei pão de queijo, e não achei grande pistola. :(

Comment: A sua dúvida é quanto à conjugação do verbo? Não consegui entender a questão.

Comment: @ANeves, blasfêmia! A guarda pontifícia te levara à justiça divina!

Comment: @Chanp, é sobre a diferença de sentido entre "ama te quem te ama" e "ama quem te ame".

Comment: Então, não me sinto qualificado a responder também. Desculpa.

Comment: @Chanp, achei que resposta era "meeeh, já sabia desd'a primeira série". Aparentemente, estou enganado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que tua interpretação está correta.

Assim, "ama quem te ama" significa o mesmo que

- "ama quem *já* te ama" ou "ama quem te ama *agora*",

enquanto "ama quem te ame" seria o mesmo que

- "ama quem *venha a te amar*" ou "ama quem *porventura te amar*".

Comment: Outro exemplo: em "Acredito que tua interpretação está correta", há certeza, mas em "Acredito que tua interpretação esteja correta", não há tanta certeza. Certeza relativa ao verbo "acreditar" — neste caso. Mas nesse caso, acredito que seja uma questão de concordância do verbo. Achas que esse comentário também está certo? Obrigadão pela resposta.

Comment: @Schilive Aqui tenho menos confiança (e acho não postaria uma resposta se você postasse), mas penso que a frase com "esteja" talvez não esteja correta, a menos que se possa dizer que haveria então um "talvez" implícito, antes do "que".